# Finding a multivariate polynomial given a list of roots

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have a very long (but not infinite) list of roots, in n dimensions. What is the most efficient way to find a non-trivial polynomial in n variables (of minimal degree) whose roots equal those in my list?

Answer (score 0):

If you have roots $x_j=(x_{1,j},\ldots,x_{n,j}) \in \mathbf{R}^n$ with $j=1,\ldots,k$, then the polynomial in $\mathbf{R}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ defined by
$$
(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^k (X_i-x_{i,j})
$$
has the above roots.